# Question 3.1.1 in AT

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, functors, algebraic-k-theory

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Show that $\operatorname{Ext}(H, G)$ is a contravariant functor of $H$ for fixed $G$, and a covariant functor of $G$ for fixed $H.$

Here is a solution I found online:

> [image]
> [image]

**Here are my questions:**

1- why $H^1(F,G) = \operatorname{Ext}(H,G),$ is this by the universal coefficient theorem?

2- Why the author is calling $H^1(F,G)$ the homology group of the dual at the end of the paragraph that begins with the word "suppose"? should not it be called cohomology? He is also doing this in the last paragraph.

3- Where is actually the proof that $(\beta \alpha)^* = \alpha* \beta*$ in the solution? he did not say why we reversed the order.Also, why in the last paragraph $(\beta \alpha)_*$ does not reverse the order? Is there a commutative diagram for proving so?

Could anyone help me answer these questions please?

Comment: Hello: thanks for citing your source, but frankly you're going to have to use _more than two characters_ if you want it to be helpful.  The question at the top of your post will make a much better title, too. That is, unless you want to be overlooked.

Comment: @rschwieb I am not fully understanding this statement " use more than two characters if you want it to be helpful".... maybe you want me not to post pictures? ....... .Also, do you want me to change the title of the question? ..... I would be happy to be overlooked for my mistakes yes :)

Comment: "Question 3.1.1 in AT"  To find your book, the only thing readers have to go on is "AT".  At that rate, it's almost like you did not say anything about where the problem came from at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's the definition. Hatcher says on p. 195, "Thus the only interesting group $H^n(F;G)$ is $H^1(F;G)$. As we have seen, this group depends only on $H$ and $G$, and the standard notation for it is $\mathrm{Ext}(H, G)$."
2. Sure. But homology, cohomology, it doesn't really matter what you call it. Start with a (co)chain complex and compute kernels mod images.
3. If we have $H \xrightarrow{\alpha} H' \xrightarrow{\beta} H''$, then we have the composite $(\beta \alpha): H \to H''$. Now apply $\mathrm{Hom}(-, G)$ to get $(\beta \alpha)^* = \alpha^* \beta^*$ on Hom. Now extend both of these maps on the chain cocomplexes: extend $(\beta \alpha)^*$ and extend each map separately. By the uniqueness part of Lemma 3.1, they induce chain homotopic maps on the cochain complexes, and hence they induce the same map on cohomology: on Ext we also have $(\beta \alpha)^* = \alpha^* \beta^*$.

Comment: what is the object that the contravariant Ext functor is taking in this case and what is the morphism? and between what categories it is operating? ..... Also in this case our hom functor is contravariant ...... am I correct? that is why the arrows are reversed ..... I believe when we use the covariant the arrows will not be reversed ..... am I correct?

Comment: There are two relevant functors: $\mathrm{Hom}(-, G)$ and $\mathrm{Ext}(-, G)$, both going from abelian groups to abelian groups. We're applying these to $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\beta \circ \alpha$. These functors are both contravariant, meaning precisely that they reverse the directions of the arrows. A covariant functor preserves the direction.

Comment: In  the solution, in the proof of the covariant part, should not we have free resolutions for $G$ instead of $H$?

Comment: Also, why $\alpha_i's $ in this case are from "Hom " to "Hom" and not from the free resolutions to the free resolutions as in the contravariant case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: I didn't write $\alpha_i'$ anywhere. You start with a map $\alpha: H \to H'$, then apply Hom to get $\alpha^* : Hom(H', G) \to Hom(H,G)$, then get an induced map $\alpha^*: Ext(H', G) \to Ext(H,G)$. You could write the first $\alpha^*$ as $Hom(\alpha, G)$ if you wanted, and write the second $\alpha^*$ as $Ext(\alpha,G)$: you're applying the contravariant functors $Hom(-,G)$ and $Ext(-,G)$ to the map $\alpha$.

Comment: I am speaking about the solution I shared in my question (not you) and I meant the $\alpha_i$ in the last paragraph of it. And I am speaking about the covariant case not the contravariant one.

Comment: First, Ext is (quite intentionally) defined using free resolutions of the domain $H$, but not of the codomain $G$. In this part of the solution, $\alpha$ is a map $G \to G'$ but the resolution is of $H$: the map $\alpha$ has nothing to do with $H$ until you apply the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(H,-)$.

Comment: But why he has to prove that $\alpha_i$ is a chain map in the line before the last paragraph?

Comment: You have to prove that it's a chain map to know that it induces a map on homology.

Comment: Does not this follow direclty from lemma $3.1$ the author used? ....... Also, I did not get what exactly is the effect of the contravariant functor $Ext$ on the maps between abelian groups and the effect of the covariant functor $Ext$ on these maps as well. Could you clarify this to me please?

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions here. Better to open up a new post on this site with a clear focused question, rather than to follow up with many many questions in comments.

Comment: Sure, thank you!